# world of Warcraft subscription

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have typed in the world of Warcraft battlechest code on the cd to see what whould happen and it took me to a screen to buy a subscription. buti didn't have money so I left. a month later I had money and I typed in the code agin to get the subscription but it said I already activated the code so I closed out the screen and opened a new one and went to battle.net. and went to account management, world of Warcraft,game time and subscription and got the 15$ monthly plan. my question is do I have the wow battle chest subscription with tbc and wotlk up to level 80?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to contact Blizzard Customer Service, either by phone, email, or in-game ticket. Even if we could guess what happened with your account, they are the ones who know for sure, and the ones who can fix your subscription if needed.

Comment: thank you are the calls toll free?

Comment: just go here: https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/contact
and fill in your information and the things you need, they will call you if you select that you want to be called!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you activated the subscription on the account that you entered the Battlechest CD key on, the answer is yes.

A quick way to find out is by going to "Account" and looking at the games you currently have unlocked on your account.  If you see World of Warcraft, click on it and it will also show you active or inactive account statuses.

All the information you will ever need is on your Battle.net account page.  If you find anything wrong or need further assistance(subscription time or World of Warcraft game not listed), your best bet would be to contact Blizzard support.

Comment: Glad I could help!